# nginx reverse proxy to apache: php doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php5

I'm trying to make a reverse proxy from nginx to apache on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. It is working fine right now with HTML files... the requests are sent directly to apache. But whenever I visit a PHP file, I see a nginx `502 bad gateway` error. I'm guessing this means that there's a problem with apache's PHP configuration.

Here's the message I get from the nginx error log:

```
2012/01/02 09:48:06 [error] 27834#0: *2445 upstream prematurely closed connection
while reading response header from upstream, client: myIP,
server: mydomainname, request: "GET /phpsite/ HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8090/phpsite/", host: "mydomainname"
```

I've already tried using [several](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/linux-notes/apache2-virtual-hosts-php-config.file) [guides](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_install-and-configure-php) to install PHP on apache several times; nothing resolves the error.

Is my nginx/apache config incorrect? If so, how should I add PHP to it?

**Edit: I fixed it!** Apparently PHP installed two plugins for caching (apc and XCache) which interfered with each other. In the php log file I found out about this:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'XCache' because conflicting module 'apc' is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I removed apc and restarted apache. Now it works fine.

Comment: what happens when you try to access http://127.0.0.1:8090/phpsite/? try it on the server with curl.

Comment: I tried, but I don't think that will work (because apache is looking for a server name)

Comment: Here's the output:
```% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
142   284  142   284    0     0  34846      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 40571```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access the PHP site on apache directly without going through nginx.

To enable PHP on your apache, you need to install the PHP module `libapach2-mod-php5`. If you are being prompted to save PHP file, you need to make sure you have a line similar to this in your apache config:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Don't forget to reload/restart your apache server after modifying the configuration.

Comment: I cannot `apt-get install libapach2-mod-php5`, but I already have php5 installed.